# Use the current UserManager in another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Hello I have 2 controllers:

- ApplicationUserController
- ApplicationProductController

How can I use `ApplicationUserController` _userManager to allow only `[Authorize]` requests inside `ApplicationProductController`. Everytime I attempt to register a new product as an authorized user I'm getting this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyAPI.Controllers.ApplicationUserController' while attempting to activate 'MyAPI.Controllers.ApplicationProductController'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired) at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at AspNetCoreRateLimit.RateLimitMiddleware 1.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `[Authorize]` attribute above your `Controller` class to make users being authorized to access controller and methods, otherwise redirect them to login page.

I think you are trying to `inject` a controller (ApplicationUserController) in another controller (ApplicationProductController). It's wrong, remove the parameter from constructor.

> You don't have to inject `UserManager` into into controller to make sure users are authorized to access controller.

This error is raised because you are trying to inject something into your controller which is not registered in `Dependency Injection`.
Please check your constructor of `ApplicationUserController` and be sure that all parameters are registered in DI at `Startup.cs` file in root of your project.

> You can find cause of error more easily by checking differences between `ApplicationUserController` constructor and `ApplicationProductController` constructor.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well seems like the problem was in the `Authorize` position as well as in the second `UserManager` I had set. Now the only thing is that I cannot get the Id of the user that registered the product:

`string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
 ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);`

Comment: If your just need user id, use: `var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

Comment: If you need the user: `var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` where `User` is accessible in controller. It is from controller base.

Comment: Tried these lines seems like the problem remains I dont know how to set the `User` in controller base